# How does one determine the physical load address of various ELF file sections?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, elf

When I objdump an ELF file emitted from GHS Multi, the physical address fields for each section is set to 0; however, section file offsets are available, but those offsets do not correspond to the memory region addresses from the linker directive file so alone, offset is not sufficient; as they appear to be file offset only.

Question: How does one compute the physical load address for each section?

My idea is to read through the ELF file and determine the load address for each of the 90 sections and then check to see what memory range the address falls within. In this manner, I can tally memory usage for each memory region; internal sram, external sram, flash, dataflash, etc.

Is the idea flawed? Is there something else I am missing?

No virtual addressing is used.  It is a simple executable intended for a 32-bit micro-controller.  We are running an RTOS on a Renesas RH850. There is no MMU or MPU active. The program entry point is hooked directly to the processor reset vector; exception: We use a small boot loader in production but jump directly from the boot loader to the start address of the image.

I wish I could share the map file or ELF, but unfortunately, it is not mine to share. I can, however, share the output of `readelf`.

There are 92 section headers, starting at offset 0xa2d6b0:

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] /DISCARD/         PROGBITS        00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 2] .text             PROGBITS        00000000 000040 0c596a 00  AX  0   0  2
  [ 3] .data             PROGBITS        00000000 0c59b0 0038b8 00  WA  0   0  8
  [ 4] .bss              NOBITS          00000000 000000 0033b0 00  WA  0   0  8
  [ 5] .entry_section    PROGBITS        00000000 0c9268 0000e8 00  AX  0   0  2
  [ 6] .vectorTableCOde  PROGBITS        00000000 0c9350 000004 00  AX  0   0  2
  [ 7] .rela.text        RELA            00000000 0c9354 0a4b14 0c     89   2  4
  [ 8] .rela.entry_secti RELA            00000000 16de68 000108 0c     89   5  4
  [ 9] .rela.vectorTable RELA            00000000 16df70 00000c 0c     89   6  4
  [10] .rodata           PROGBITS        00000000 16df7c 135928 00   A  0   0  4
  [11] .note.renesas     NOTE            00000000 2a38a4 000050 00      0   0  4
  [12] .bss_sram         NOBITS          00000000 000000 07acd0 00  WA  0   0  8
  [13] .rbss             NOBITS          00000000 000000 00b5dc 00  WA  0   0  8
  [14] .rela.data        RELA            00000000 2a38f4 002124 0c     89   3  4
  [15] .rela.rodata      RELA            00000000 2a5a18 00d41c 0c     89  10  4
  [16] .rela.ghsinfo     RELA            00000000 2b2e34 000774 0c     89  88  4
  [17] .slbss            NOBITS          00000000 000000 003534 00  WA  0   0  8
  [18] .applicationInfo  PROGBITS        00000000 2b35a8 000040 00   A  0   0  4
  [19] .applicationEnd   PROGBITS        00000000 2b35e8 000014 00   A  0   0  4
  [20] .R_FDL_Text       PROGBITS        00000000 2b35fc 0016ea 00  AX  0   0  2
  [21] .rela.R_FDL_Text  RELA            00000000 2b4ce8 001278 0c     89  20  4
  [22] .R_FDL_Const      PROGBITS        00000000 2b5f60 000014 00   A  0   0  4
  [23] .R_FDL_Data       NOBITS          00000000 000000 000064 00  WA  0   0  4
  [24] .OS_CONST         PROGBITS        00000000 2b5f80 0002b4 00   A  0   0 16
  [25] .rela.OS_CONST    RELA            00000000 2b6234 000624 0c     89  24  4
  [26] .OS_CODE          PROGBITS        00000000 2b6858 0114c0 00  AX  0   0  4
  [27] .rela.OS_CODE     RELA            00000000 2c7d18 0094b0 0c     89  26  4
  [28] .OS_CORE0_CONST   PROGBITS        00000000 2d11c8 002af0 00   A  0   0  8
  [29] .OS_CORE0_VAR_NOI NOBITS          00000000 000000 001604 00  WA  0   0  8
  [30] .rela.OS_CORE0_CO RELA            00000000 2d3cb8 0040bc 0c     89  28  4
  [31] .OS_STACK_BLETASK NOBITS          00000000 000000 001000 00  WA  0   0  4
  [32] .OS_STACK_BSWTASK NOBITS          00000000 000000 001000 00  WA  0   0  4
  [33] .OS_STACK_CANCM_T NOBITS          00000000 000000 000400 00  WA  0   0  4
  [34] .OS_STACK_CANCOM_ NOBITS          00000000 000000 000800 00  WA  0   0  4
  [35] .OS_STACK_CLITASK NOBITS          00000000 000000 000400 00  WA  0   0  4
  [36] .OS_STACK_CPUMONI NOBITS          00000000 000000 000400 00  WA  0   0  4
  [37] .OS_STACK_CHIMEAP NOBITS          00000000 000000 001388 00  WA  0   0  4
  [38] .OS_STACK_CHIMEDR NOBITS          00000000 000000 000fa0 00  WA  0   0  4
  [39] .OS_STACK_DIRANAB NOBITS          00000000 000000 000400 00  WA  0   0  4
  [40] .OS_STACK_DIRANAD NOBITS          00000000 000000 000320 00  WA  0   0  4
  [41] .OS_STACK_EXTAMPT NOBITS          00000000 000000 000800 00  WA  0   0  4
  [42] .OS_STACK_HWTIMER NOBITS          00000000 000000 000320 00  WA  0   0  4
  [43] .OS_STACK_IPC2TAS NOBITS          00000000 000000 000400 00  WA  0   0  4
  [44] .OS_STACK_IPCMPTA NOBITS          00000000 000000 000400 00  WA  0   0  4
  [45] .OS_STACK_IDLETAS NOBITS          00000000 000000 000400 00  WA  0   0  4
  [46] .OS_STACK_IPCGATE NOBITS          00000000 000000 000400 00  WA  0   0  4
  [47] .OS_STACK_KEYTASK NOBITS          00000000 000000 000800 00  WA  0   0  4
  [48] .OS_STACK_LOGGERT NOBITS          00000000 000000 000800 00  WA  0   0  4
  [49] .OS_STACK_MODULEM NOBITS          00000000 000000 000800 00  WA  0   0  4
  [50] .OS_STACK_NVMTASK NOBITS          00000000 000000 001000 00  WA  0   0  4
  [51] .OS_STACK_OSCORE_ NOBITS          00000000 000000 000800 00  WA  0   0  4
  [52] .OS_STACK_OSCORE_ NOBITS          00000000 000000 001000 00  WA  0   0  4
  [53] .OS_STACK_OSCORE_ NOBITS          00000000 000000 000400 00  WA  0   0  4
  [54] .OS_STACK_OSCORE_ NOBITS          00000000 000000 000400 00  WA  0   0  4
  [55] .OS_STACK_OSCORE_ NOBITS          00000000 000000 000800 00  WA  0   0  4
  [56] .OS_STACK_OSCORE_ NOBITS          00000000 000000 000400 00  WA  0   0  4
  [57] .OS_STACK_OSCORE_ NOBITS          00000000 000000 000400 00  WA  0   0  4
  [58] .OS_STACK_OSCORE_ NOBITS          00000000 000000 000400 00  WA  0   0  4
  [59] .OS_STACK_OSCORE_ NOBITS          00000000 000000 000400 00  WA  0   0  4
  [60] .OS_STACK_OSCORE_ NOBITS          00000000 000000 001000 00  WA  0   0  4
  [61] .OS_STACK_OSCORE_ NOBITS          00000000 000000 000800 00  WA  0   0  4
  [62] .OS_STACK_OSCORE_ NOBITS          00000000 000000 000800 00  WA  0   0  4
  [63] .OS_STACK_POLLING NOBITS          00000000 000000 000400 00  WA  0   0  4
  [64] .OS_STACK_PWRAMPT NOBITS          00000000 000000 000800 00  WA  0   0  4
  [65] .OS_STACK_RTCTASK NOBITS          00000000 000000 000400 00  WA  0   0  4
  [66] .OS_STACK_TESTSIM NOBITS          00000000 000000 000400 00  WA  0   0  4
  [67] .OS_STACK_TIMERTA NOBITS          00000000 000000 000400 00  WA  0   0  4
  [68] .OS_STACK_VEHCFG3 NOBITS          00000000 000000 000960 00  WA  0   0  4
  [69] .OS_STACK_VEHCFG4 NOBITS          00000000 000000 000320 00  WA  0   0  4
  [70] .OS_STACK_VEHCFG5 NOBITS          00000000 000000 0004b0 00  WA  0   0  4
  [71] .OS_STACK_VIDEOIN NOBITS          00000000 000000 000800 00  WA  0   0  4
  [72] .OS_STACK_HWPWRCT NOBITS          00000000 000000 0005dc 00  WA  0   0  4
  [73] .OS_STACK_SENSORT NOBITS          00000000 000000 000514 00  WA  0   0  4
  [74] .OS_STACK_STARTUP NOBITS          00000000 000000 0008fc 00  WA  0   0  4
  [75] .OS_STACK_SYSCTRL NOBITS          00000000 000000 000dac 00  WA  0   0  4
  [76] .OS_STACK_VEHCFG1 NOBITS          00000000 000000 0005dc 00  WA  0   0  4
  [77] .OS_STACK_VEHCFG2 NOBITS          00000000 000000 0005dc 00  WA  0   0  4
  [78] .OS_EXCVEC_CORE0_ PROGBITS        00000000 2d7d80 0001fc 00  AX  0   0 512
  [79] .OS_INTVEC_CORE0_ PROGBITS        00000000 2d7f80 000800 00  AX  0   0 512
  [80] .rela.OS_EXCVEC_C RELA            00000000 2d8780 000180 0c     89  78  4
  [81] .rela.OS_INTVEC_C RELA            00000000 2d8900 001800 0c     89  79  4
  [82] .OS_VAR_NOCACHE_N NOBITS          00000000 000000 00000c 00  WA  0   0  4
  [83] .OS_CORESTATUS_CO NOBITS          00000000 000000 000014 00  WA  0   0  4
  [84] .OS_BARRIER_CORE0 NOBITS          00000000 000000 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [85] .bootstrap        PROGBITS        00000000 2da100 000040 00  AX  0   0  2
  [86] .rela.bootstrap   RELA            00000000 2da140 000018 0c     89  85  4
  [87] .gstackfix        PROGBITS        00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  4
  [88] .ghsinfo          NOTE            00000000 2da158 000480 00      0   0  1
  [89] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 2da5d8 261080 10     90 110134  4
  [90] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 53b658 4f173c 00      0   0  1
  [91] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 a2cd94 00091c 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  p (processor specific)
```

Comment: Generally, if the address is (or VMA+LMA are) zero, that means you have an ELF file that has not yet been linked and hence no addresses are assigned yet. The object file must be read by a linker, which will assign addresses. If the linker is a dynamic linker, it will assign them based on whatever's running right now. If it is a static linker, it will build a loadable image with pre-assigned addresses.

Comment: I ma pretty sure its the final linked file.  There is a map generated along with it, but i feel as though there is still some stuff missing because even the map only shows offsets and no full addresses where the SRAM base address is present; as well as other memory base addresses.

Comment: I stand corrected.  The map file does show ORIGIN + size for each section.  I wonder why the origin doesnt seem to be available as physical address in the elf.  Should it be or do i need to dig through elf headers to determine the origin for each section?

Comment: Torek - You were spot on!  Thank you.  The linker generates a relocatable object file with the extention .elf.  This file then runs through the linker a second time where a second core's relocatable object is also included.  They are fully linked and packaged in to a multi-core archive file which the debugger uses to load memory.  I opened the .mca with 7-zip and extracted the image file which had the addressed filled in. A+

Comment: Ah, you have one of those two-pass linkage setups for some reason. (I have no idea what the reason is on your system, but there probably is one. :-) )